# Content overlapping in navigation menu?

Tags: uinavigationbar

I have a navigation menu on top and the content overlaps the navigation menu. What I want is that the content must be below the navigation bar. How to fix this? Help me please?

Here is the screenshot:
http://s1277.photobucket.com/user/fuscia_pink19/media/ss_zps888fc3e9.png.html

As you can see the aaaa letters are on the navigation bar also.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

nav {
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 28%;
right: 16%;
font-size: 20px;
}

nav li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}

nav li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #a4d0dd;
padding: 11px 25px;
}

#wrap {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background-color: black;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #444444;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">

<nav>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">Home</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">My Profile</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Account</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Logout</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div><!-- ENDING TOP_MENU DIV -->
<div class="content">
a<br />

a<br />

a<br />

a<br />

a<br />

a<br />

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `position:fixed` in `#wrap`.

Comment: Hello putvande thanks for answering but i also want the navigation to stay on top. Because i want a scrollable navigation? Like in facebook.

Comment: The screenshot is different than your code. With this code the content is behind the navigation.

Comment: The code is the same in the screenshot. I just removed the background-color in the id #wrap to see if it will overlap in the navigation menu. I just want the "a" letters to be below the navigation menu but the navigation will always stay on top no matter how many contents will be on the content. Btw thanks for answering.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but add this line to your CSS an see if that is what you want: `.content { margin-top:80px; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the content 'below' the navigation you need to add a `margin-top` that has the same height as your navigation bar, in this case '80px'

So you add this line to your CSS:

```
.content { margin-top: 80px; }
```